CSP not showing on browser
I'm quite new to coding, and I'm developing an application using Express, Node JS and Angular. Right now, I am focusing on security, so I did some research and found the Content Security Policy, which could help me. I did some testing and everything seems to work fine on the side of the backend, but not on the browser.
app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy:{
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
      scriptSrc: ["'self'"],
      styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
      imgSrc: ["'self'"],
      connectSrc: ["'self'"],
      fontSrc: ["'self'"],
      objectSrc: ["'none'"],
    },
  },
}))

It works fine on Insomnia

But the headers of my application don't show the CSP header that is suppose to be there:

So I would like to know why, and if is an error, how to solve it. Thank you!

Index.html will be served as a static file.  Just add this to  of index.html in your IDE:   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
img-src data: https: http:;
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />  Anything more restrictive will need some extra buggery.  Angular already has some good built-in XSS protections for input.

on a side note:  using wildcard "*" for allowed origins is pretty darn insecure.  Thankfully any credentialed requests won't go through, but you should avoid setting any CORS headers unless you absolutely need to.  (You are LOOSENING security by setting those)  If you do have to allow certain origins, list them explicitly.
